# Confused about freeing malloc memory in the loop

Tags: loops, malloc

I just finished pset5 of cs50, and one of functions is meant to load content of a dictionary into a hash table. Inside the loop in said function i have to malloc memory for a node that i will later assign to node in the hash table.

When i tried freeing node n after each loop iteration my function wouldn't work.
When i don't free it it does work and more confusingly it also passes valgrind check and cs50's check50 for memory leaks.

My questions are :

1. how would i free 'node n' to allow my function to still work?
2. Why doesn't valgrind detect any memory leaks when i don't free 'n' ? Is it example of undefined behavior ?
3. How does malloc in a loop work, does it allocate new chunk of memory each time or does it overwrite previous chunk of memory ?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code :

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{

    //Setting counter to determine wheather node comes second in linked list or not.
    int counter = 0; 
    //declaring string array to store words from dictionary
    char word1[LENGTH +1]; 
    
    FILE *dic = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(dic == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //Loop loading words from dictionary to hash table
    while(fscanf(dic, "%s", word1) != EOF )
    {
        node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            return false;
            free(n);
        }

        int i = hash(word1);
        //Storing word in temporary node
        strcpy(n->word, word1);
        n->next = NULL;
        //Three different conditions(first node of[i], second node of[i], and after second node of[i])
        if(table[i] == NULL)
        {
            table[i] = n;
            counter++;
            counter2++;
        }
        else if (counter == 1)
        {
            table[i]->next = n;
            counter = 0;
            counter2++;
        }
        else
        {

            n->next = table[i];
            table[i] = n;
            counter2++;
        }


    }
    
    fclose(dic);
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't free memory in load. You free it in unload. That was the whole point.
2. If valgrind doesn't detect memory leaks, then presumably you have a working unload function. Why would it be undefined behaviour?
3. It will allocate new memory every time. This wouldn't work if it didn't.

Comment: I think i just understood that when i assign pointer 'node n' to 'table[i]' , table[i] overtakes memory assigned to 'node n' is that correct? That would explain everything. Sorry I'm still getting my head around some basic concepts.

Comment: @WojtekZ yes, table[i] takes ownership of that memory.